# Evento voltar para a data anterior quando houver um evento já cadastrado no mesmo horário

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Como faço para que o usuário ao arrastar um evento para outra data no mesmo horário, ele retorne para a data anterior? Ele já emite um alerta caso o evento seja no mesmo horário, mas ele só volta a data anterior quando aperto F5. Veja abaixo a estrutura:

```
<script src="fullcalendar/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/locale/pt-br.js'></script>

     <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {

       var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         validRange: {
             start: '<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>'
         },
         header: {
           left: 'prev,next today',
           center: 'title',
           right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
         },
         defaultDate: Date(),
         navLinks: true,
         editable: true,
         eventLimit: true,
         eventClick: function(event) {
           $('#visualizar #id').text(event.id);
           $('#visualizar #id').val(event.id);
           $('#visualizar #title').text(event.title);
           $('#visualizar #title').val(event.title);
           $('#visualizar #start').text(event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
           $('#visualizar #start').val(event.start.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
           $('#visualizar #color').val(event.color);
           $('#visualizar #description').val(event.description);
           $('#visualizar').modal('show');
           return false;
         },
         selectable: true,
         selectHelper: true,
         select: function(start, end){

           $('#cadastrar #start').val(moment(start).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
           $('#cadastrar #end').val(moment(end).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
           $('#cadastrar').modal('show');
         },
         events:<?php echo $metodos->visualizarAgenda($idEmpresa,$idUsuario); ?>,

         eventDrop:function(event)
         {
           var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
           var title = event.title;
           var id = event.id;

          $.ajax({
           url:"alterar-dia-agenda.php",
           type:"POST",
           dataType: 'JSON',
           data:{start:start,id:id},

           success:function(sucesso){

             if(sucesso.hasEvent == false){
               $('#confirmar').modal('show');
                temporiza();
                calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
             }else{
              $('#erro').modal('show');
              temporiza();
               calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
             }
            }
          });
         }
       });
      });
      </script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Utilize o evento [**updatEvent**](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/updateEvent) para atualizar a data. Caso esteja utilizando o `momentjs`, basta utilizar o método `subtract` para alterar a data.

Comment: Olá Valdeir. Perdão, não consegui entender, pois conheço muito pouco jquery e fullcalendar. Nesse caso, o evento voltaria para a data anterior caso o usuário arraste para uma data com horário já existente?

Comment: A atualização estou conseguindo fazer, o problema é que quando arrasto um evento para uma determinada data com o mesmo horário, ele consegue fazer essa verificação, porém não retorna a data anterior, somente quando aperto F5.

Comment: Poste o código do evento de arrastar, só com o código do *Ajax* fica complicado pois não sei se você está utilizando `momentjs`, qual evento você está manipulando, são sei os valores das variáveis `start` e `id` etc.

Comment: Certo. Postei o código completo.

Comment: Segue exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/valdeirpsr/gnhevdt4/4/ Ps.: Não vai funcionar no site `jsfiddle`

Comment: Certo Valdeir. Vou acessar o link e adaptar no meu código.

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia meu camarada, essa função de emitir um alerta de alteração de reunião na mesma hora como foi realizada ? não consegui achar nada ainda.